# Using a WinForm as a Windows Installer Custom Action

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, windows-installer, custom-action

I am working on in installer project that needs to gather some info and act on it during the install (mainly online key retreival and registration). The Setup Project UserInterface templates seem inflexible and poorly documented so I am looking at opening a WinForm as a Custom Action.

I know this is possible because I see reference to it in many places but this is my first Windows Installer experience and so far it is mired in googled contradictions, partial or outdated information and guesswork... erg....

Does anyone have (even a pointer to) a clear concise description of how one gets this done in a VS 2008 WinForm project...

Many thanks for inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the .net framework is installed when the installer is launched  (especially on Windows XP). A best practice is to keep your installer away from any dependencies.

Put the online key retrieval and registration in your application rather than doing all that stuff during install.

Comment: hmmm thanks will give that a think... this is for an Office Add-In product so pretty sure .net would be there and not sure how it would impact the user experience, but maybe an idea

Comment: So, you have install conditions(requirements). If the requirement of .NET is not satisfied, the ".NET isn't installed" message-box appear and install dies; OR .NET is pre-installed as a pre-requisite. So, I don't think is a serious problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a standard [installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) class. In the class create your form and show it (ShowDialog is prefered)